# How to handoff animation for iOS developers?

Tags: ios, animation, hand-off

I'm a designer and interested in different ways I can handoff animation to iOS developers and the best ways to do that depending on a particular case.

**1. JSON**

I know [Lottie](https://lottiefiles.com/featured) works best for animating micro-interactions and creating an animated illustration, like those on onboarding pages. For a designer, it's easy to provide JSON file since it can be generated with [Bodymovin](https://airbnb.io/lottie/after-effects/bodymovin-installation.html) plugin in AfterEffects. The developer just gets the file and uses it as is, no more additional efforts for him.

**2. Swift or Objective C**

iOS has different animation API, like UIView so a developer can recreate animation from a video or designer can explain it in words. In this case, the developer has to code everything himself.

**3. Export from design tools**

Some design tools are able to export into Swift or Objective C. [Flow](https://createwithflow.com) is able to generate Swift code, [Framer](https://www.framer.com) does it as well.

**What are other technologies developers use to create animations?**

**What type of files, prototypes designers should provide for the developer considering different cases?**

Answer (score 1):

Each app developer has their own method for building and there are numerous ways to do it, as such, there is no set method. As UI/UX designers, our goal for the app developer is that they build out the app as we had imagined it. Therefore, you should ask the developer that you are working with what they need from you to develop the app. The goal is to make it as easy as possible for them to integrate what it is you are trying to do.

At the most basic level you should provide:

- .svg icons with separate states (ie. clicked, not clicked)
- fonts with sizes
- hexadecimal color palette
- images
- an overlaid grid at the main resolution of key app screens (no need to show repeating designs) that explicitly states the positioning of elements (x px, y px)
- the app architecture which shows the content on each page and how they link
- a list of animations (if any)

This might be a better question to ask in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as you are asking what a developer needs from a designer. Although careful how you word it. I could imagine them closing it due to it being a bit of a [subjective question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have asked the question on StackOverflow and it was downvoted as not related to programming and I was advised to ask it here.

Comment: Hahaha I figured. They're very uptight over there. How did you phrase the question?

Comment: @Davborg, I phrased it exactly as it did here. Moreover, I have already asked a very similar question on StackOverflow that was well received and answered. The question was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620499/how-to-handoff-animation-for-android-developers So I don't know why would they disapprove almost the same question, maybe they hate iOS over there :D

Answer (score 0):

- Origami, https://origami.design/
- Kite Compositor

They both let's you export code to iOS.